# So Weird . the static variable come out early but then disappeared

Tags: c++, mfc, static

Here is my code, it's too long, so I just show parts that matter:

```
CObList &m_list=CManagerView::my_students;
m_list.AddHead(stu);
```

`my_student` is a static variable of class `CManagerView`, and this code is working well, but then I want to save the data of `m_list`, in another section:

```
CObList& m_list=CManagerView::my_students;
m_list.Serialize(ar);
```

and when I'm looking at `m_list` in the debugger's watch window, it shows

> Error: symbol m_list  not found

I can't figure out the reason for it, it's so weird.  Is there something I've missed?

Comment: I don't understad your question. Are you saying that program produces incorrect output? Or are you saying that your IDE is failing to display your data? If the former, please provide a **short**, **complete** program (see http://sscce.org). If the latter, please tell us what IDE you use.

Comment: @Robᵩ - I've edited the question ab it, and I think the OP has the latter problem, the IDE does not show the value of `m_list`

Comment: Is `CObList` your class or is it coming from a library you just linked against?

Comment: "So Weird . the static variable come out early but then disappeared"... I hate it when my static variables come out early and then disappear, don't you? *laugh*

Comment: A few possibilities come to mind: if you have a watch window or similar where you manually add variables too, try deleting it from there then re-adding; alternatively the variable may not be in scope at the point you've stepped to.

Comment: The matter is the student is just available at first  and unavailable later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've added the first `m_list` in the watch window you'll have problems because the other `m_list` is a different variable that just happens to have the same name as the first one.

Comment: The ide should pick up on that and use the current context

Comment: I work it out! The stack is corrupted! It's my fault cause i'm so stupid. I'm sorry , thank guys.